# How to print an equation in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've got a question.

```
1.0X + 1.0Y + -7.0 = 0
```

How can I print an equation better?

For example, instead of +- 7.0 I'd like to print -7.0; or in a case with zero coefficients.

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: just it: puts "\n#{a}x + #{b}y + #{c} = 0"

Comment: but i know i could use 'if...else', i'd like to do it more effectively

Comment: So, you'll need to add logic to add the appropriate text as you build the output string.  For instance, if a coefficient is negative, you may want to wrap it in parenthesis, or if the preceding operation is addition, you may want to change it to subtraction.  Likewise, if a coefficient is 0, you can simply just not add it to the string.  In the end, you're going to need to use logic in your program to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few substitutions, you could achieve a much cleaner equation :

```
equation = "1.0X + 1.0Y - -0.0Z + -7.0 = 0"

new_equation = equation.gsub('+ -', '- ')
                       .gsub('- -', '+ ')
                       .gsub(/^\s*\+/, '')             # Remove leading +
                       .gsub(/(?<=\d)\.0+(?=\D)/, '')  # Remove trailing zeroes
                       .gsub(/\b1(?=[a-z])/i, '')      # Remove 1 in 1X
                       .gsub(/[+-]? ?0[a-z] ?/i, '')   # Remove 0Z

p new_equation

# "X + Y - 7 = 0"
```

By the way, as much as I love Ruby, I must say that [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html) is an awesome project. This library alone makes it worthwhile to learn the basic Python syntax.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't Sympy now a Python wrapper around [SymEngine](https://github.com/symengine/symengine)? Because there's a Ruby wrapper around [SymEngine](https://github.com/symengine/symengine.rb) as well.

Comment: Thank you for an answer! But I've got one more question. What should I do, if I want to remove '0' in a case, when an equation is `0x+0y+0-0`
I've tried that: `.gsub('0',' ')`, but it also removes the last zero.

Comment: @StepanMorozov: See update. I don' think it's 100% robust, but it seems to work fine for simple cases.

Answer (score 3):

Prints an equation with full control of formating

```
a = b = 1
c = -7
puts "%0.1fX + %0.1fY %s %0.1f = %d"%[ a, b, c < 0 ? '-' : '+', c.abs, 0 ]
```

output:

```
1.0X + 1.0Y - 7.0 = 0
```

---

Documentation: [Ruby's % string operator / sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)